# Switch cases with onmouseover and onmouseout events

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case, onmouseover, onmouseout

I've been trying to get a switch to work with both onmouseover and onmouseout, but i don't know how to bind it to the events. Thanks in advance for your help

```
<script>
function img(img){
switch(img)
{
case "showSq": 
document.getElementById("square").innerHTML = '<img src="square.png">';
break;
case "hideSq": 
document.getElementById("square").innerHTML = '';
break;
case "showCr": 
document.getElementById("circle").innerHTML = '<img src="circle.png">';
break;
case "hideCr": 
document.getElementById("circle").innerHTML = '';
break;
}}
</script> 
<body>
<div id=right>
<h1> Geometry </h1>
<p>
<span onmouseover="img(showSq)" onmouseout="img(hideSq)"> SQUARE</span>,
<span onmouseover="img(showCr)" onmouseout="img(hideCr)"> CIRCLE </span>
</p>
<p> <span id="circle"> <span id="square"> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: your params should be as img('showSq') values inside quotes as static string

Comment: Thanks, fixed, but it still doesn't make it work.

Comment: I just tested it and it works!

Comment: May i know which browser were you using ? I really can't get it to work in chrome.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your params should be as img('showSq') and `<span>` tags are missing `</span>` tags

```
<p> <span id="circle"></span> <span id="square"></span> </p>
```

Comment: The </span> tags are there, but  adding '' to params only makes circle work for some reason

Comment: Then it could be a typo or a missing image file. Can you create a fiddle or pen ?

Comment: It seems that circle is overriding square. When i run my mouse over square it works, but after i try that with circle the square stops doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

add single courts to make a string of function parameter

```
<span onmouseover="img('showSq')" onmouseout="img('hideSq')"> SQUARE</span>,
<span onmouseover="img('showCr')" onmouseout="img('hideCr')"> CIRCLE </span>
```